# Recording debugger for Scala

Tags: scala, debugging

I wonder if there exists a recording debugger for Scala, no matter the supported IDE. By recording debugger I means a debugger that allows to reproduce the evolution of the app, straight and back in time.

I saw the product "takipi", but it is specialised in exception handling, and if I'm not making a mistake, it does not allow to navigate in time.

What I am searching exists but for Java: it is Chronon. They do not want to extend their product to Scala although.